# How can my PCI device driver remap PCI memory to userspace?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, segmentation-fault, linux-device-driver, qemu

I am trying to implement a PCI device driver for a virtual PCI device on QEMU. The device defines a BAR region as RAM, and the driver can do ioremap() this region and access it without any issues. The next step is to assign this region (or a fraction of it) to a user application.
To do this, I have also implemented an .mmap function as part of my driver file operations. This mmap is simply using remap_pfn_range, but it also passes the pfn of the memory pointer returned by the ioremap() earlier.

However, upon running the user space application, the mmap is successful, but when the app tries to access the memory, it gets killed and I get the following dmesg errors.

"
a.out: Corrupted page table at address 7f66248b8000

..Some page table info..

Bad pagetable: 000f [#2] SMP NOPTI

..and the core dump..
"
Does anyone know what have I done wrong? Did I missed a step? Or it could be an error specific to QEMU?
I am running x86_softmmu as my QEMU configuration and my kernel is the 4.14

Comment: The phrase "but is also passes the pfn of the memory pointer returned by the ioremap() earlier" sounds like you are trying to mmap the mmio virtual address used by the kernel. Do not do that. Whatever address is returned by `ioremap()` is irrelevant as far as `mmap`ing the PCI BAR region is concerned. You should be `mmap`ing the physical addresses of the PCI BAR region. Also, replace `remap_pfn_range` with `io_remap_pfn_range` when `mmap`ing PCI BAR region memory.

Comment: Hi @IanAbbott and thanks for your reply.
The code to instantiate the device itself contains the function
 memory_region_init_ram() , which is qemu specific and basically says that the memory that the bar refers to is RAM.
"You should be mmaping the physical addresses of the PCI BAR region."
Are you referring to mmap directly from the user app? But I do not want to mmap the PCI BAR region directly from user space. I want the kernel module to be the owner of this address space, that can be handed over to userspace applications ondemand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this issue and managed to map PCI memory to user space via the driver. As [@IanAbbott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5264491/ian-abbott) implied, I've changed the `pfn` input of the `remap_pfn_range()` function I was using in my custom `->mmap()`.

The original was:

```c
io_remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, pfn, vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start, vma->vm_page_prot));
```

where the `pfn` was the result of the buffer pointer return from the `ioremap()`. I changed the `pfn` to:

```c
pfn = pci_resource_start(pdev, BAR) >> PAGE_SHIFT;
```

That basically points to the actual starting address pointed by the BAR. My working `remap_pfn_range()` function is now:

```c
io_remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, pci_resource_start(pdev, BAR) >> PAGE_SHIFT, vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start,vma->vm_page_prot);
```

I confirmed that it works by doing some dummy writes to the buffer pointer in my driver, then picking up the reads and doing some writes in my user space application.